# Neighborhood collectives-reduce operation

Tags: graph, mpi

I need the allreduce (MPI_Ineighbor_allreduce) for collective communication in MPI, unfortunately it is not included yet.
The obvious, not so efficient solution, is to use MPI_Neighbor_alltoall
at the expense of increasing buffer size, Do you have any suggestions?
Is there any plan to include this in future releases?

Thanks

Comment: @_Hasbestein Why do you think you need it? What is your situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no such thing as `MPI_Neighbor_allreduce` in the MPI standard.
if you want it, feel free to ask for it at http://mpi-forum.org/

btw, did you mean to use `MPI_Neighbor_allgather` instead of `MPI_Neighbor_alltoall` in order to implement the neighbor allreduce ?