# MPI neighbor reduce operation

Tags: mpi, nearest-neighbor, topology, cartesian-coordinates

This is the moment I feel I need something like `MPI_Neighbor_allreduce`, but I know [it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45596180/5825294).

**Foreword**

Given a 3D MPI cartesian topology describing how a 3D physical domain is distributed among processes, I wrote a function `probe` that asks for a scalar value (which is supposed to be put in a simple `REAL :: val`) given the 3 coordinates of a point inside the domain.

There can only be `1`, `2`, `4`, or `8` process(es) that are actually involved in the computation of `val`.

- `1` if the point is **internal** to a process subdomain (and it has no neighbors involved),
- `2` if the point is **on a face** between 2 processes' subdomains (and each of them has 1 neighbor involved),
- `4` if the point is **on a side** between 4 processes' subdomains (and each of them has 2 neighbors involved),
- `8` if the point is **a vertex** between 8 processes' subdomain (and each of them has 3 neighbors involved).

After the call to `probe` as it is now, each process holds `val`, which is some value for involved processes, `0` or `NaN` (I decide by (de)commenting the proper lines) for not-involved processes. And each process knows if it is involved or not (through a `LOGICAL :: found` variable), but does not know if it is the only one involved, nor who are the involved neighbors if it is not.

In the case of `1` involved process, that only value of that only process is enough, and the process can write it, use it, or whatever is needed.
In the latter three cases, the sum of the different scalar values of the processes involved must be computed (and divided by the number of neighbors `+1`, i.e. self included).

**The question**

What is the best strategy to accomplish this communication and computation?

**What solutions I'm thinking about**

I'm thinking about the following possibilities.

1. Every process executes `val = 0` before the call to `probe`, then `MPI_(ALL)REDUCE` can be used, (the involved processes participating with `val /= 0` in general, all others with `val == 0`), but this would mean that if more points are asked for `val`, those points would be treated serially, even if the set of process(es) involved for each of them does not overlap with other sets.
2. Every process calls `MPI_Neighbor_allgather` to share `found` among neighboring processes to make each involved process know which one(s) of the `6` neighbors participate(s) to the sum and then perform individual `MPI_send`(s) and an `MPI_recv`(s) to communicate `val`. But this would still involve every process (even though each communicates only with the `6` neighbors.
3. Maybe the best choice is that each process defines a communicator made up of itself plus the `6` neighbors and then use.

**EDIT**

For what concerns the risk of deadlock mentioned by @JorgeBellón, I initially solved it by calling `MPI_SEND` before `MPI_RECV` for communications in the positive direction, *i.e.* those corresponding to even indices in `who_is_involved`, and vice-versa in the negative direction. As a special case, this could not deal with a periodic direction with only two processes along it (since each of the two would see the other one as a neighbor in both positive and negative directions, thus resulting in both processes calling `MPI_SEND` and `MPI_RECV` in the same order, thus causing a deadlock); the solution to this special case was the following *ad-hoc* edit to `who_is_involved` (which I called `found_neigh` in my code):

```
DO id = 1, ndims
    IF (ALL(found_neigh(2*id - 1:2*id))) found_neigh(2*id -1 + mycoords(id)) = .FALSE.
END DO
```

As a reference for the readers, the solution that I implemented so far (a solution I'm not so satisfied with) is the following.

```
found = ... ! .TRUE. or .FALSE. depending whether the process  is/isn't involved in computation of val
IF (      found) val = ... ! compute own contribution
IF (.NOT. found) val = NaN

! share found among neighbors
found_neigh(:) = .FALSE.
CALL MPI_NEIGHBOR_ALLGATHER(found, 1, MPI_LOGICAL, found_neigh, 1, MPI_LOGICAL, procs_grid, ierr)
found_neigh = found_neigh .AND. found

! modify found_neigh to deal with special case of TWO processes along PERIODIC direction
DO id = 1, ndims
    IF (ALL(found_neigh(2*id - 1:2*id))) found_neigh(2*id -1 + mycoords(id)) = .FALSE.
END DO

! exchange contribution with neighbors
val_neigh(:) = NaN
IF (found) THEN
    DO id = 1, ndims
        IF (found_neigh(2*id))     THEN
            CALL MPI_SEND(val,                 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, idp(id), 999, MPI_COMM_WORLD,                    ierr)
            CALL MPI_RECV(val_neigh(2*id),     1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, idp(id), 666, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
        END IF
        IF (found_neigh(2*id - 1)) THEN
            CALL MPI_RECV(val_neigh(2*id - 1), 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, idm(id), 999, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
            CALL MPI_SEND(val,                 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, idm(id), 666, MPI_COMM_WORLD,                    ierr)
        END IF
    END DO
END IF

! combine own contribution with others
val = somefunc(val, val_neigh)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `MPI_Neighbor_allreduce` does not exist.
You can create derived communicators that only include your adjacent processes and then perform a regular `MPI_Allreduce` on them. Each process can have up to 7 communicators in a 3D grid.

- The communicator in which a specific process will be placed in the center of the stencil.
- The respective communicator for each of the adjacent processes.

This can be a quite expensive process, but it does not mean it could be worthwhile (HPLinpack makes extensive use of derived communicators, for example).

If you already have a cartesian topology, a good approach is to use `MPI_Neighbor_allgather`. This way you will not only know how many neighbors are involved but also who it is.

```
int found; // logical: either 1 or 0
int num_neighbors; // how many neighbors i got
int who_is_involved[num_neighbors]; // unknown, to be received
MPI_Neighbor_allgather( &found, ..., who_is_involved, ..., comm );

int actually_involved = 0;
int r = 0;
MPI_Request reqs[2*num_neighbors];
for( int i = 0; i < num_neighbors; i++ ) {
  if( who_is_involved[i] != 0 ) {
    actually_involved++;
    MPI_Isend( &val, ..., reqs[r++]);
    MPI_Irecv( &val, ..., reqs[r++]);
  }
}
MPI_Waitall( r, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE );
```

Note that I'm using non-blocking point to point routines. This is important in most cases because `MPI_Send` may wait for the receiver to call `MPI_Recv`. Unconditionally calling `MPI_Send` and then `MPI_Recv` in all processes, may cause a deadlock (see [MPI 3.1 standard section 3.4](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report-book.pdf)).

Another possibility is to send both the real value and the found in a single communication, so that the number of transfers are reduced. Since all processes are involved in the `MPI_Neighbor_allgather` anyway, you could use it to get everything done (for a small increase in the amount of data transferred it really pays off).

```
INTEGER :: neighbor, num_neighbors, found
REAL :: val
REAL :: sendbuf(2)
REAL :: recvbuf(2,num_neighbors)

sendbuf(1) = found
sendbuf(2) = val
CALL MPI_Neighbor_allgather( sendbuf, 1, MPI_2REAL, recvbuf, num_neighbors, MPI_2REAL, ...)

DO neighbor = 1,num_neighbors
  IF recvbuf(1,neighbor) .EQ. 1 THEN
     ! use neighbor val, placed in recvbuf(2,neighbor)
  END IF
END DO
```

Comment: It is not clear to me how to put in practice the first solution (the first two bullets in your answer). For what concerns the _second approach_, I've already defined the MPI cartesian topology; to point is that, for each process involved, not all 6 surrounding processes are involved as well. Please, read again the question and help me improved it if needed. So far I've relied on the solution I thought of, but I think I'll try the one in your last bullet point. I'll let you know as soon as I'll have had time to give a try to it.

Comment: I missunderstood your question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The chunk of code you wrote is basically the first part of the solution I hypothesed in my point 2. (And that I&#39;ve actually adopted so far). Indeed, I used your `who_is_involved` as a base to perform individual `MPI_SEND`/`MPI_RECV` among those processes who are involved to share (and sum, and blablabla) `val`.

Comment: If you perform multiple point to point communications (send/recv) between neighbors, I strongly suggest you to use `MPI_ISEND`, `MPI_IRECV` and `MPI_WAITALL` routines instead. It reduces the risk of deadlocks (wrong order in user code) and improves the efficiency (allows parallelism in communication). I think this alternative is the best one, because *unexpected receive* routines such as `MPI_PROBE` are very inefficient.

Comment: Jorge Bellón, please, give a look to my self-answer to gain more insight.

Comment: Alright. I added a new alternative, which I think its the most elegant so far (it is similar to `MPI_MAXLOC` reduction). Consider putting your example in the question, so that people can see it straight away.